# With Sharepoint 2010 Excel Services how can I get values from a spreadsheet with version control

Tags: c#, version-control, sharepoint-2010

I can get the values from a xlsx file and bind them to a gridview within a webpart in sharepoint 2010.

But I do want to use version-control for this document library containing spreadsheets.
Is there any way for me to select the specific versioned spreadsheet and use it for reading data.

For example:

- abc.xlsx (version 3.0)
- abc.xlsx (version 2.0)
- abc.xlsx (version 1.0)

I want to gather info from version 2.0, how can I?

*Thanks in advance*(:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no better suggestiones provided, I've found a simple way:

First get the file, then using GetVersions select a specific versioned one, then read the file and make modifications necessary.

I guess no quickie for this one available.